# Copy a cell from Google sheet containing text with both normal and bold text to GMail causes entire text with bold

Tags: google-sheets, gmail

1. Open Google Sheets
2. Put the text "Normal **Bold**" in a cell
3. Copy the cell and paste in Gmail

Actual : Entire cell is bold

Expected : Same as cell in Google sheets

Note : This behavior is bad in case one had a Sheet table to copy, which might have different formatting in different cells...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

Unfortunately Stack Overflow isn't the right forum to post issues in Google products.

You can however report this directly to Google by following the menu path `Help > Report a problem` directly from the [Google Sheets interface](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/create) when viewing a sheet. A pop-up will appear entitled `Send feedback`, in which you can describe this issue.

#### Workaround:

In the mean time - if you double click the cell and copy the text rather than copying the whole cell, the typographical emphasis is kept in the same way - the text Normal **Bold** copies over to Gmail with only the word 'Bold' in bold.

#### References:

- [Create a Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/create)

Comment: Yeah, but my actual issue is that of copying a whole table. So, I have to fix this for every cell ...Thanks by the way for confirming my hunch !